# jQuery and Django form validation re-load and submit event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, forms

I'm trying to save/validate a django form via an AJAX POST request.

Everything works just fine when the submit button is hit the first time, but, if the server-side validation fails and the form needs to be loaded again for the user to update the inserted contents, the event listener is not catching any further submit event and the default behavior applies.

This is the related code I have under $(document).ready(function()

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/saveForm/',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#myForm').html(data);
    });
});
```

In other words : once the html code of the form has been replaced using the `$('#myForm').html(data);` instruction the `$(document).on('submit'...` is not anymore going to be called on submit events despite jquery's `on` event listener is supposed to work with future elements matching the selector.

EDIT:

Binding the click event on the form submit button works.

```
$(document).on('click', '#myFormSubmit', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/saveForm/',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#myForm').html(data);
    });
});
```

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure what is wrong, but I have a feeling it has to do with the done method (because maybe after the a failed run, it doesn't know what to do). You might need to explicitly tell it what to do in case of failure:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.post({
        url: 'ajax/saveForm/',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
                alert('yey!');
            },
        error: function(response) {
                form.html(data);
            }
    });
});
```

I also avoided $() the entire document, used $.post and cashed the form object into a variable, but those shouldn't have any actual effect (they're just conventions). Tell me if this works or not, I'll try and help. Also, try using chrome developer tools (i.e console.log(whatever)), it's really great for debugging

Comment: same issue using your code, I think here it is more a javascript event listener related problem. When the html code of the form is replaced using the form.html(data) instruction the on('submit' event catcher is not catching submit events anymore.

Comment: Then maybe try binding it to a different event. $('#mySubmitButton').on('click' ...

Comment: binding it to the submit button works, still can't figure out why it did not work on the form submit event. To me it makes more sense to bind the submit event rather than the click event; but still, thanks for help. :)

Comment: Sure thing! I can't say exactly why it didn't work either, but you could try opening the chrome console and add an event listner, maybe you'll find out what is happening